# Find a word in a file with a given SHA-256 hex digest Python

Tags: python, encryption, hash, blockchain, sha256

I'm trying to find a word whose ASCII encoding has the following SHA-256 hex digest:
"69d8c7575198a63bc8d97306e80c26e04015a9afdb92a699adaaac0b51570de7" using the hashlib.

With my code a accomplished to sort through the file and return the digest that matches but i need it into an actual word , i know that hash cant be decrypted so i need help with the logic on how to print the actual word.

here is my code:

```
import hashlib

def q1 ():

    file = open("words.txt","r")
    for x in file : 
        x = x.strip('\n')
        x = (hashlib.sha256(x.encode("ascii", "ignore")).hexdigest())
        wordFound ="69d8c7575198a63bc8d97306e80c26e04015a9afdb92a699adaaac0b51570de7"

        if x == wordFound:
            print (x)



q1()
```

this is the list of words:

https://inst-fs-iad-prod.inscloudgate.net/files/a405f779-7d37-41fe-ac80-30712573f273/dict.txt?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.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.VL380_FMQhjjUMatFJNHkJSW-e__o6fS7idrpcCSA94atgpTQVAQtMZmm-YxX2pJYm3OaxP1bUej8GgY4nvxMg

Comment: If you want to print the word x, why do you overwrite x?

Comment: i overwrite it because all words have /n at the end so first i need to remove it , then convert to digest

Comment: New at programming? Why not use two variables `word` and `digestOverWord` or similar? You do **not** need to **convert** to digest, you just need the digest.

Comment: Thank you for that hint! i found a solution